# I am new to Gatling Tool. how do we coorelation and parametrization in gatling tool

Tags: gatling

As in jmeter tool we have reg exp or boundry extracter elements to capture server values. like that how can we do corrleation in GATLING.

Left Boundary =>   EVENTVALIDATION" value="

Right Boundary=>    "

Regular Expression =>  EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\"

ALso how to do perametrization in GATLING. 
Like jmeter we have csv data set configuration. how can we confige csv file in GATLING tool.

Please help how to do correlation and parametrization in GATLING tool

Answer (score 0):

These questions are answered comprehensively in the gatling documentation.

https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/#advanced-tutorial - check out the section "Step 03: Use dynamic data with Feeders and Checks"